How to smooth 3D data for a contour plot
I have 3D data, but it is very noisy and is not regular shape in any dimension.
I want to create a contour plot by smooth the data in the third dimension.
Furthermore, I initially used this command to plot the data with some degree of smoothing
data = Import["data.csv"];    
ListDensityPlot[data, Frame -> True, 
      MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 5, InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
      MaxPlotPoints -> 25];

but is still very noisy, the results
here is an example of the data
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1560X2T31GgqNnhq6jLCk9NzKiR64a8sA/view?usp=sharing
Kind regards

Please post the data.

plot = Normal[    ListDensityPlot[data, Frame -> True, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},      Mesh -> 5, InterpolationOrder -> 2, MaxPlotPoints -> 25]]; {plot, plot /.   Line[pts_] :> BSplineCurve[pts, SplineDegree -> 6]} ?

Thanks I didnt know about BSpline functions, I will try to use it.

You may fit a simple smooth function. E.g. we may fit a quadratic surface like:
 f = Fit[data, {1, x, y, x  y, x^2, y^2}, {x, y}]
pl = Plot3D[f, {x, 5, 20}, {y, 10, 40}];
pts = Graphics3D[Point[data]];
Show[pl, pts]



The fit of a polinomial function unfortunately takes away the real topology of the data, I tried using even a 4th grade but is not good.

And what is the "real topology of the data"? You may try other forms like e.g. "BSplineSurface" or "ParametricPlot3D"
